# How can I convert an existing project to angular-cli?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I just tried [`ng2-admin`](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-admin) and it's looking great; all of the features are really good. How can I convert this project to `angular-cli`?

I tried with `ng init`, but it is overwriting the existing code in the `app` folder. How can I convert this project to `angular-cli` without any impact?

Comment: It's not going to be quite that straightforward, as you have additional dependencies and the CLI handles webpack configuration in a different way. Create a `ng new` project then migrate code across, rather than trying to convert in-place.

Answer (score 6):

just create project in angular-cli and than put your all code in app folder src/app folder. import external dependencies if your project have.

Comment: This is what I did when changing over to angular-cli aswell - the only extra thing that I can contribute here is that to make sure that any assets and global scripts are defined into the angular-cli.json file