# How to configure css associated to mdl-select on angular 2 quickstart solution

Tags: css, angular2-mdl

I am trying to use an mdl-select component in a form on angular 2 but the component is showing in drop drown state the whole time. I assume it is because I have not associated css with it but am unsure how to do this in angular 2  quickstart solution. Any guidance appreciated...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzQBo.jpg)

Thanks:)

Comment: I have added css as below to main viewport (index.html) and get some styling now only issue still being that mdl-select is permanently  dropped down. Scrolling works, highlight works, selection works but drop down just stays 'open'. Any ideas?     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.indigo-pink.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/@angular2-mdl-ext/select/select.css" />

Comment: I get similar behaviour re drop down state of mdl-select as this plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/3GHZHgxOGhDdrfAQHlv2?p=preview. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. After trying different things, this is what worked for me: I added SASS styles .scss to ‘styles’ array of angular-cli.json. Instead of .css files to index.html. And, we have to add scss for popover component, too, as that is the one used internally. You don’t have to import the popover component, though, unless you are using it elsewhere.

***angular-cli.json***

"styles": [

```
    "styles.css",

    "../node_modules/@angular2-mdl-ext/select/select.scss",

    "../node_modules/@angular2-mdl-ext/popover/popover.scss"
  ],
```

Comment: Thanks I am not using angular-cli.json though. Was wondering if it would work if I set the component's style to. Scss file. Could you post your whole angular-cli.json please? How do I convert quickstart to use cli approach?

Comment: Check this post to convert an existing project to angular-cli http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40673567/how-can-i-convert-an-existing-project-to-angular-cli

Comment: You can also add styles array to component code. I tried and it worked.

Comment: Sweet thanks a mill mate. Will let you know how it goes ;)

Comment: Thanks I converted to angular-cli and resolved the issue I had. Related issue though, the select label (floating or otherwise) does not seem to show. The placeholder functionality is fine but label is non-existent once item is selected. Did you face this issue as well?