# How to Build Angular 2.4.4 project for server

Tags: angular

My problem is that i need to build project but is the first time and i diden't find how to create bulid.json
My pakage.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "some simple app",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/common": "2.4.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.4",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.4",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.4",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.4.4",
    "angular2-bootstrap-switch": "^0.2.3",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.21",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "css-toggle-switch": "^4.1.0",
    "mydatepicker": "^2.0.31",
    "mydaterangepicker": "^4.1.9",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "1.3.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.3",
    "systemjs": "0.20.0",
    "zone.js": "0.7.6",
    "tslint": "^5.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "3.1.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.3"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

I'm new in Angular 2 and if i correctly understand that to run site on Apache for simple web servers i need to build it i tried to run

```
ng build
```

but tells me that ng is not installed but if run

```
npm start
```

site is opening and works correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need [Angular CLI](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli)

`npm install -g angular-cli`

Once you have this, you can run `ng build`.

Read the documentation, it provides a lot of useful information including targeting different build environments for prod/dev etc, running tests, creating new components/directives...

A useful guide to converting to a CLI app:

https://github.com/asnowwolf/angular-cli/commit/515b57933688b37a389c84ee079d9b840a043666

Comment: I runed   npm install -g angular-cli  . I get this error   You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the build command.

Comment: Here is a guide on how to do it. Theoretically it shouldn't take long at all, but there are a few steps to take and once done you wont need to do it again https://github.com/asnowwolf/angular-cli/commit/515b57933688b37a389c84ee079d9b840a043666 and a guide on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40673567/how-can-i-convert-an-existing-project-to-angular-cli

Comment: I updated to Angular 4 and installed cli but on ng build gives me  ( ERROR in ./src/app/Pages/contact.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './pages/contact.component.html' in '/Volumes/Git/m.zbor.md/src/app/Pages'
 ) but on npm start worcks fine

Comment: Well 
`1. npm install @angular/cli
2. created .angular-cli.json in root of site (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-cli)`